# PHP cURL post data is not sent to target url

Tags: php, curl

Maybe it's duplicate question. I have tried any solution with similar question with mine that I can find and implemented it to my probs, not a single solution is work. I need to use PHP curl to get data from other systems (B). But in the B the data I sent is not defined or no data was sent. curl process is success target url is just right.

Curl in my system

```
$data['tag']    = 'getData';
$data['periode'] = $this->input->post('periode');
$url = 'http://example.com/service/index.php';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, sizeof($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// I use follow location cause I get moved permanently notice
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $output;
```

And in B system I check with this

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

the ouput is `array(0) {}`.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: sorry I have afk for recent time. But I just post my own answer for this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have my own solution for this.
I just need to set the URL to `https` insetad of `http`, because the backend program is redirecting all the non secure protocol `http` to the secure one `https`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS in a query string format.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "tag=val&periode=val");
```

Also you should just be setting CURLOPT_POST to 1 as it just specifies if it should use a POST request.

You can use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php to build a query string from an array.

Comment: I have tried `http-build-query` and has no effect. still return `array(0) {}`

Comment: Are you sure it is sending a POST request? Have you tried setting CURLOPT_POST to 1 explicitly? If so I could be wrong about curl needing to pass query parameters as I think newer versions you don't need to

Comment: ya I edit `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);` is there another way to check if my curl is in post request?

Comment: Check your webserver's access or error logs

Comment: I assume my webserver access has post request. Because I have other service request with post and it was complete